# Eclipse Neon Hangs on Save

Tags: eclipse, performance, slowdown, eclipse-neon

Is it common that Eclipse Neon always hangs on saving a file?

I work on a 16 Gigs, Windows 7 system and allocated 5 gigs of memory for eclipse. Still when I save a file within my project, its a nightmare. It takes almost 90 - 120 seconds to let me control again. Its extremely pathetic and annoying. I believe NetBeans is far advanced and easier to use. I have tried all possible solutions to optimize the performance and eventually considering moving the entire workspace to NetBeans. Any comments are welcome. The below message keeps appearing on error log.

[image: This message keeps appearing on Error Log]

Comment: Where's the file physically going? What kind of file is it? In what kind of project?

Comment: No it isn't common. You need to tell us more about what you are doing.

Comment: I am not doing anything abnormal. I have 20 projects (8 EJB, 8 Utility, 2 Web, 2 EAR) within my workspace. The same set up used to work fine with Eclipse Kepler. Only after upgrading to Neon, the problem arises when ever I select save, workshop just freezes and refuses to respond for at least 60 seconds. Any tips on optimizing are highly appreciated.

Comment: Move to IntelliJ. There are no such annoying issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the issue resolved. Removing all the break points resolved the issue. Now save happens in less than 1 second.

Comment: Well, in my case it hangs for ever, and I don't have any breakpoints.
The issue may be because I use samba and the project has tons of files.